# C# KEYEVENTF_KEYUP doesn't work in specific app

Tags: c#, key, emulation, user32

I need to emulate some keys, here the code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1;
private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2;

public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
{
    keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
}

public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
{
    keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

KeyboardSend.KeyDown(Keys.Z);
KeyboardSend.KeyUp(Keys.Z);
```

But in one specific application "KeyUp" method doesn't work and is depressed until i press key on keyboard.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Consider putting a small **delay** between your KeyDown() and KeyUp() calls: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);`

Comment: I tried this already :(

Comment: Have you tried `SendKeys.SendWait("z");` ? ...why are you using `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` here?

Comment: I need to depress key and get it up when i need.

Comment: Z is not an extended key though.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx): _The extended keys consist of the ALT and CTRL keys on the right-hand side of the keyboard; the INS, DEL, HOME, END, PAGE UP, PAGE DOWN, and arrow keys in the clusters to the left of the numeric keypad; the NUM LOCK key; the BREAK (CTRL+PAUSE) key; the PRINT SCRN key; and the divide (/) and ENTER keys in the numeric keypad._

Comment: Maybe you could use a tool like Spy++ and watch the messages that app receives as keys are pressed normally on the keyboard, versus when they are sent via code.  I can't think of anything else to do...sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway.

It's work on other applications, my specific app accept WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN, changing KEYEVENT to WM_KEY make no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The only change I see in **Ryan West**'s solution, is that he removed the `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag away from calling function `keybd_event` in the third argument, in both `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` methods, so as a result, in `KeyDown` method, the third argument of calling `keybd_event` function is 0, and in `KeyUp` method, it is only `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`.
That only small change caused `KeyUp` method to work and solve your problem.

Read about `keybd_event` function in MSDN site **properly**, and even **again**, if you read before.

They give information and details about that function and its arguments. They also explain all the flags that you can use in the third argument of `keybd_event` function, especially the case in your problem `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY`.

If you will read **properly** and **again**, **maybe** you will understand why `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag causes your `KeyUp` method **not** to work, and why you have to remove that flag, in order to cause your `KeyUp` method to work.

You **may** also learn how, in the **future**, to call `keybd_event` function **correctly**, so you won't get any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the code to the following it seemed to work just fine. I tested it by opening notepad, running the program, then holding down the 'a' key. It printed lowercase for 3 seconds, then started doing uppercase then went back to lowercase again.

```
public static void KeyDown(Keys vKey)
{
    keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void KeyUp(Keys vKey)
{
    keybd_event((byte)vKey, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
KeyDown(Keys.SHIFT);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
KeyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
```

Try checking out Windows Input Simulator for a good example of how to simulate key presses. It's an open source wrapper for the SendInput function in User32.dll.

One thing I've learned is that to simulate holding a key down, it usually isn't enough to send the keydown, wait a bit, then send the key up. If you want the key to repeat the key press like a normal keyboard does you have to keep sending the keyboard event and end it with a key up event.

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/