# KeyUp when test is completed Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests which I run with Selenium. I often need to send short cut keys in my tests.

However, sometimes for a bizarre reason, keys don't get released. So at the end of each test I want to release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. I try and perform a <kbd>keyUp</kbd> once I send my keys. However, this doesn't always work. Is there a way I can release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys at the end?

My code is as follows for they <kbd>KeyDown</kbd>/<kbd>KeyUp</kbd>

```
Actions action = new Actions(excelSession);
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).KeyDown(Keys.Alt).SendKeys(Keys.Tab).KeyUp(Keys.Control).KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Perform();
```

I tried doing something like this to release keys at the end but it didn't work

```
action.KeyUp(Keys.Control).Perform();
action.KeyUp(Keys.Alt).Perform();
action.KeyUp(Keys.Shift).Perform();
```

However this didn't work correctly.

Comment: You can use the System.Windows.Input.Keyboard class to determine the state of the ctrl, alt, shift keys and then using user32.dll keybd_event function you can perform a key up if needed. Search on those will give you tons of examples.

Comment: Just as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978170/c-sharp-keyeventf-keyup-doesnt-work-in-specific-app

Comment: @jibbs at the moment you solutions seems to work. Thank you very much :)